# Which is the Java Class in the ngdbc JAR that can be used to open the database connection to SAP HANA

Tags: java, jar, hana

Using the Jar file [ngdbc.jar](https://github.com/varunkaruna1986/VarunPublicDocuments/blob/master/ngdbc.jar) (EDIT: invalid link to user's GitHub, see valid link in answer), I am able to make connection to a SAP HANA database, as is shown in this screenshot:

[image: Successful Connection To HANA From Squirrel Client]

However I would like to know which one of the classes from the jar will actually contain the connection pool settings that I can use.

**I would really appreciate it if some one can help me out with the method/class name. From the JAR I am trying to find the following information:**

1. The name of the method that has the data source object instantiated.
2. The name of the method that has the Connection Pool Data Source object instantiated.

Comment: Have You Considered Consulting the Documentation?

Comment: And Trying to Taper Off the Capital Letters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ngdbc` JAR contains the SAP HANA JDBC driver. You can actually obtain it from Maven central: [com.sap.cloud.db.jdbc:ngdbc](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sap.cloud.db.jdbc/ngdbc). You should prefer this method rather than storing it on your GitHub - where you might actually infringe upon its license which does not allow for redistribution as far as I know.

The [Driver](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Driver.html) implementation is `com.sap.db.jdbc.Driver`. As you can see, drivers have a `Connection connect(String url, Properties info) throws SQLException` method that you can use to connect to the database.

For managing pools of connections, I would recommend using a dedicate library like [HikariCP](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP) or the [Tomcat Connection Pool](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html). Basically you would need to do something along the lines of:

```
HikariDataSource ds = new HikariDataSource();
ds.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:sap://localhost:30115/?databaseName=Test");
ds.setUsername("user");
ds.setPassword("password");
ds.setDriverClassName("com.sap.db.jdbc.Driver");
```

Alternatively, you can use the `com.sap.db.jdbcext.HanaConnectionPoolDataSource` directly, which is included in the ngdbc JAR, but which is more limited in respect to performance and configuration options.

The SAP HANA reference documentation also covers the [JDBC Application Programming](https://help.sap.com/viewer/0eec0d68141541d1b07893a39944924e/2.0.03/en-US/434e2962074540e18c802fd478de86d6.html) topic with example programs.

Comment: Good answer. I just added the link to the reference documentation as it covers the OP's question and should be a resource every HANA programmer should be aware of.

Comment: I just want to say a big thank you to @Serban-Petrescu. Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for giving such a detailed answer, I am 1000% sure your suggestion will work.

Thank you to LaraBr